# What font is used during verbose boot mode?

Tags: macos, startup, font, kernel

When booting OS X in verbose boot mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on startup), the log is printed on screen.

It seems different to the kernel font, but it might just be a smaller version of it.

[image: Screenshot of a verbose boot (inverted) Yosemite 10.10.1]
inverted screenshot Yosemite 10.10.1

Anyone know what font is used and have a credible source?

Comment: I suggest you to take a photo and upload to [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Comment: @jherran I can't get a clear enough photo. The text is far too small on a Retina display and too pixelated on a standard display, not to mention that a photo instead of a screenshot isn't really good enough when there's so many similar fonts it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font used seems to be a somewhat nameless cowboy apparently just called Iso-Font and was made by [Ka-Ping Yee](http://zesty.ca). He doesn't seem to care about this accomplishment, since he does not list it on his CV.

The sources for this font are compiled into the kernel and the sources to that are to be found at [https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.70.16/](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.70.16/osfmk/console/iso_font.c.auto.html)

In there it simply says:

```
/*
 * ISO Latin-1 Font
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2000
 * Ka-Ping Yee <ping@lfw.org>
 *
 * This font may be freely used for any purpose.
 */
```

This rather unsatisfactory naming seems to be accurate nevertheless, as an email transcript on Russian site reveals:

[Ka-Ping Yee ISO Latin-1 Font in linux kernel](https://init-6.bitbucket.io/content/2010/10/ka-ping-yee-iso-latin-1-font-in-linux-kernel/)

That site also illustrates how to use this on a Linux console and  will show you how it looks when booting linux:

[image: Iso-Font booting Linux]

Comment: Anyone who puts a gold medal in the International Math Olympiad at the very bottom of a long CV obviously has more important things to care about ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here
kayover.deviantart.com/art/OS-X-Darwin-Bitmap-Font-609139414

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions.  To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -